# Acl Plugin doesn't work at cakephp 2

Tags: json, cakephp, plugins, acl

I am using cakePHP version 2.4.10.
I installed Acl plugin, [here](http://www.alaxos.org/blaxos/downloads/get/alaxos_acl_2.2.0.zip)

But, recently, the Website had been closed.
I think you can't jump the above link. The website's domain is www.alaxos.org.
Does anyone know what happened? And which plug-in is alternative version of it?
I think this was popular ACL plugin.

Anyway, I use the old version of the Acl plugin. And it doesn't work.

I can access the control panel, and apply the permission to each action.
But it doesn't work. So for example, I can do delete action which I forbid it in Acl Plugin.

In addition, nevertheless I forbid access to json file, it show some error message.

it says

```
Warning (512): DbAcl::check() - Failed ACO node lookup in permissions check. Node references:
Aro: Array

[User] => Array
        (
            [id] => **************(I cant show you)
            [unique_key] => **************(I cant show you)
            [username] => **************(I cant show you)
            [email] => **********************************(I cant show you)
            [group_id] => 3
            [created] => 2014-11-19 13:03:33
            [modified] => 2014-11-20 08:29:38
            [Group] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [name] => users
                    [created] => 2014-06-12 12:36:32
                    [modified] => 2014-06-12 12:36:32
                )

        )

)

Aco: contorollers/Eventnames/json [CORE/Cake/Model/Permission.php, line 103]
```

Does anyone understand this message?

my file  `app/Config/bootstrap.php` is

```
<?php
/**
 * This file is loaded automatically by the app/webroot/index.php file after core.php
 *
 * This file should load/create any application wide configuration settings, such as
 * Caching, Logging, loading additional configuration files.
 *
 * You should also use this file to include any files that provide global functions/constants
 * that your application uses.
 *
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * For full copyright and license information, please see the LICENSE.txt
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright     Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link          http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @package       app.Config
 * @since         CakePHP(tm) v 0.10.8.2117
 * @license       http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php MIT License
 */

// Setup a 'default' cache configuration for use in the application.
Cache::config('default', array('engine' => 'File'));

/**
 * The settings below can be used to set additional paths to models, views and controllers.
 *
 * App::build(array(
 *     'Model'                     => array('/path/to/models/', '/next/path/to/models/'),
 *     'Model/Behavior'            => array('/path/to/behaviors/', '/next/path/to/behaviors/'),
 *     'Model/Datasource'          => array('/path/to/datasources/', '/next/path/to/datasources/'),
 *     'Model/Datasource/Database' => array('/path/to/databases/', '/next/path/to/database/'),
 *     'Model/Datasource/Session'  => array('/path/to/sessions/', '/next/path/to/sessions/'),
 *     'Controller'                => array('/path/to/controllers/', '/next/path/to/controllers/'),
 *     'Controller/Component'      => array('/path/to/components/', '/next/path/to/components/'),
 *     'Controller/Component/Auth' => array('/path/to/auths/', '/next/path/to/auths/'),
 *     'Controller/Component/Acl'  => array('/path/to/acls/', '/next/path/to/acls/'),
 *     'View'                      => array('/path/to/views/', '/next/path/to/views/'),
 *     'View/Helper'               => array('/path/to/helpers/', '/next/path/to/helpers/'),
 *     'Console'                   => array('/path/to/consoles/', '/next/path/to/consoles/'),
 *     'Console/Command'           => array('/path/to/commands/', '/next/path/to/commands/'),
 *     'Console/Command/Task'      => array('/path/to/tasks/', '/next/path/to/tasks/'),
 *     'Lib'                       => array('/path/to/libs/', '/next/path/to/libs/'),
 *     'Locale'                    => array('/path/to/locales/', '/next/path/to/locales/'),
 *     'Vendor'                    => array('/path/to/vendors/', '/next/path/to/vendors/'),
 *     'Plugin'                    => array('/path/to/plugins/', '/next/path/to/plugins/'),
 * ));
 *
 */

/**
 * Custom Inflector rules can be set to correctly pluralize or singularize table, model, controller names or whatever other
 * string is passed to the inflection functions
 *
 * Inflector::rules('singular', array('rules' => array(), 'irregular' => array(), 'uninflected' => array()));
 * Inflector::rules('plural', array('rules' => array(), 'irregular' => array(), 'uninflected' => array()));
 *
 */

/**
 * Plugins need to be loaded manually, you can either load them one by one or all of them in a single call
 * Uncomment one of the lines below, as you need. Make sure you read the documentation on CakePlugin to use more
 * advanced ways of loading plugins
 *
 * CakePlugin::loadAll(); // Loads all plugins at once
 * CakePlugin::load('DebugKit'); //Loads a single plugin named DebugKit
 *
 */

//searchプラグインのロードのために記述しています。
//CakePlugin::loadAll(); //Loads all plugins at once 一回、すべてのプラグインをロード。
CakePlugin::load('Search');
//CakePlugin::load('DebugKit'); //Aclの設定をする時にはDebugKitを一時的にコメントアウトして下さい

/**
 * You can attach event listeners to the request lifecycle as Dispatcher Filter. By default CakePHP bundles two filters:
 *
 * - AssetDispatcher filter will serve your asset files (css, images, js, etc) from your themes and plugins
 * - CacheDispatcher filter will read the Cache.check configure variable and try to serve cached content generated from controllers
 *
 * Feel free to remove or add filters as you see fit for your application. A few examples:
 *
 * Configure::write('Dispatcher.filters', array(
 *      'MyCacheFilter', //  will use MyCacheFilter class from the Routing/Filter package in your app.
 *      'MyPlugin.MyFilter', // will use MyFilter class from the Routing/Filter package in MyPlugin plugin.
 *      array('callable' => $aFunction, 'on' => 'before', 'priority' => 9), // A valid PHP callback type to be called on beforeDispatch
 *      array('callable' => $anotherMethod, 'on' => 'after'), // A valid PHP callback type to be called on afterDispatch
 *
 * ));
 */
Configure::write('Dispatcher.filters', array(
    'AssetDispatcher',
    'CacheDispatcher'
));

/**
 * Configures default file logging options
 */
App::uses('CakeLog', 'Log');
CakeLog::config('debug', array(
    'engine' => 'File',
    'types' => array('notice', 'info', 'debug'),
    'file' => 'debug',
));
CakeLog::config('error', array(
    'engine' => 'File',
    'types' => array('warning', 'error', 'critical', 'alert', 'emergency'),
    'file' => 'error',
));

CakePlugin::load('Acl',array('bootstrap' => true));





















//末尾に追加したapp/Plugin/Acl/Config/bootstrap.phpのソース
App::uses('AclRouter', 'Acl.Lib');

/* -------------------------------------------------------------------
 * The settings below have to be loaded to make the acl plugin work.
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * See how to include these settings in the README file
 */

//CakePlugin::load('AclExtras');
/*
 * The model name used for the user role (typically 'Role' or 'Group')
 */
Configure :: write('acl.aro.role.model', 'Group'); //Roleから変更

/*
 * The primary key of the role model
 *
 * (can be left empty if your primary key's name follows CakePHP conventions)('id')
 */
Configure :: write('acl.aro.role.primary_key', '');

/*
 * The foreign key's name for the roles
 *
 * (can be left empty if your foreign key's name follows CakePHP conventions)(e.g. 'role_id')
 */
Configure :: write('acl.aro.role.foreign_key', 'group_id'); //空白から変更

/*
 * The model name used for the user (typically 'User')
 */
Configure :: write('acl.aro.user.model', 'User');

/*
 * The primary key of the user model
 *
 * (can be left empty if your primary key's name follows CakePHP conventions)('id')
 */
Configure :: write('acl.aro.user.primary_key', '');

/*
 * The name of the database field that can be used to display the role name
 */
Configure :: write('acl.aro.role.display_field', 'name');

/*
 * You can add here role id(s) that are always allowed to access the ACL plugin (by bypassing the ACL check)
 * (This may prevent a user from being rejected from the ACL plugin after a ACL permission update)
 */
Configure :: write('acl.role.access_plugin_role_ids', array());

/*
 * You can add here users id(s) that are always allowed to access the ACL plugin (by bypassing the ACL check)
 * (This may prevent a user from being rejected from the ACL plugin after a ACL permission update)
 */
Configure :: write('acl.role.access_plugin_user_ids', array(1));

/*
 * The users table field used as username in the views
 * It may be a table field or a SQL expression such as "CONCAT(User.lastname, ' ', User.firstname)" for MySQL or "User.lastname||' '||User.firstname" for PostgreSQL
 */
Configure :: write('acl.user.display_name', "User.username");

/*
 * Indicates whether the presence of the Acl behavior in the user and role models must be verified when the ACL plugin is accessed
 */
Configure :: write('acl.check_act_as_requester', true);

/*
 * Add the ACL plugin 'locale' folder to your application locales' folders
 */
App :: build(array('locales' => App :: pluginPath('Acl') . DS . 'locale'));

/*
 * Indicates whether the roles permissions page must load through Ajax
 */
Configure :: write('acl.gui.roles_permissions.ajax', true);

/*
 * Indicates whether the users permissions page must load through Ajax
 */
Configure :: write('acl.gui.users_permissions.ajax', true);


Configure :: write('Asset.timestamp', 'force');
```

Comment: Do you really need ACL? Or could it also be solved in a more static way? Because then I would really not touch ACL here.

Comment: I'd like to make SNS website. So I need to use ACL.

At least, I want to distinguish Administrator from users, and want to apply permissions to them.

Are there better way to build such website?

Comment: The important difference is if you need to do that row-level-based (different permissions for users with the same role), or just role based (all with the same role have the same permissions). The latter does not require the ACL overhead per se. You can simply use some simpler approach in that case, either semi-static or completely db driven.

Comment: I know that the latter approach is easier.
But I'm going to make a large website, so I wanna use any Acl PlugIn.
Which plugIn is major in the world now?

Comment: I'm sorry, The problem was solved.
I made mistakes in my code!!

I wrote every controller's components 'Auth'.

For example :
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class ClubScoresController extends AppController {
public $components = array('Auth','Session','Paginator','Search.Prg');

This is wrong. Because nevertheless I use ACL, it allows every action. 

So,

public $components = array('Session','Paginator','Search.Prg');
This is correct.

I leave out 'Auth'.

It was the cause I could access all controllers and all actions.

Thank you everyone.